# Swift - POST to endpoint works in Postman, but returns error with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the below code (swift) to try and authenticate a user. When I post to the endpoint via *Postman*, I get a success message and the user is logged in. However when I try to post the same parameters to the same URL via alamofire, I get the error:

```
{
  "message" : "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
  "code" : "rest_no_route",
  "data" : {
    "status" : 404
  }
}
```

Code below. Any idea why this is happening?

**ViewController**

```
let params: Parameters = [
        "username": "test",
        "password": "test",

        ]
    

    AF.request("http://myurl/wp-json/wp/v2/users/custom-plugin/login", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).responseJSON { AFdata in
        do {
            guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: AFdata.data!) as? [String: Any] else {
                print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                return
            }
            guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                return
            }
            guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
                return
            }
            
            print(prettyPrintedJson)
        } catch {
            print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
            return
        }
    }
```

**Postman Generated Code (Swift):**

```
import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/custom-plugin/login?username=admin&password=AFC18ny%235RQ#5RQ")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("wordpress_logged_in_538d5c69f61735bc32492fcf43069509=admin%7C1652129154%7CZY0wmXTgSoQS6e7eI9tmCG0tgI1WD5YgUEVpzO0fAuI%7C56d4596133112e03b4ac743f91a13de5fa622c2bdfc29e616b9b5ef543f4a2d2", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

request.httpMethod = "POST"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
  guard let data = data else {
    print(String(describing: error))
    semaphore.signal()
    return
  }
  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
  semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: Show the Postman code? The Swift or the cURL generated one. Did you know that Alamofire can generate also cURL description? It could help if you want to compare your own code with the working Postman one... But without knowing the Web API, nor the "working" solution, it's hard to tell what's wrong with your solution...

Comment: @Larme See postman generated code above :) P.S. - Had no idea it provided that feature, super cool.

Comment: The base url and some path aren't the same, but also the params are inside the URL, not in the body (and not JSON, but URL encodedà

Comment: have you set the appropriate App Transport Security, for `http` instead of `https` as require by apple? Or use `https`